# Is there any way to clear the Voicemail notification that was added by my app in ICS?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, voicemail

My app is using the new [VoicemailContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/VoicemailContract.html) functionality in ICS to insert voicemails that show up in the stock call log. I've got it working perfectly, but I can't figure out how to control the new Voicemail notification that pops up when the new voicemails are added. The notifications seem to be controlled by the Phone app, and even if I manually update the voicemail's IS_READ attribute, the notification doesn't go away. In fact, I can delete the voicemail altogether, and the notification doesn't go away. The only way that it goes away is if that notification is clicked, or if I manually go into the call log and open one of the new voicemails.

Does anyone have any idea on how to control that programmatically from my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. Status bar notifications can only be cleared by the app that placed them there. The phone app is the app that placed it there and this is why only that app is able to clear it.

I wish there was a way to do this myself, but currently, there is not :(

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I already suspected. It just seems odd tha there would be an API to manage all aspects of managing our own VM provider, but no way to manage the notifications for it.

Comment: There's now an app for that, on Android 4.3 and up: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsropos.clearnotifications